# Jquery Ajax not passing multiple values

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I'm trying to learn Jquery Ajax. I have a page that uses a while loop to display sql rows. I'm trying to write a script that allows user to asynchronously  delete a row using a submit button. In addition, the script will delete two files stored on the server (whose URLs are stored in the db row). I've been working on this for a couple days and I'm sure there is more than just one error. I was looking for some advice here as to how I could get this working.

As of now, when user clicks, it directs to blank page. The row and files are not deleted, and the js(confirm("")) is not popping up.

html

```
<form action="delete_list.php" method="POST" id="delete_form">
  <input type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>" name="id" />
  <input type="hidden" id="ad_link" value="<?php echo $ad_link ?>" name="ad_link" />
  <input type="hidden" id="listing_img" value="<?php echo $listing_img ?>"     name="listing_img" />
  <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
            var element = $(this);

            var del_id = element.attr("id");
            var info = 'id=' + del_id;

            var del_file = element.attr("ad_link");
            var info = 'ad_link=' + del_file;

            var del_img = element.attr("listing_img");
            var info = 'listing_img=' + del_img;
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this listing?")) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "delete_list.php",
                    data: info,
                    success: function() {}
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

php (on separate page) - Is it preferable to have this on the same page as the html?

```
<?php
require('../dbcon2.php');
if (isset($_POST['id']) && ($_POST['ad_link']) || ($_POST['listing_img'])) {
    $idc = $_POST['id'];
    unlink($_POST['ad_link']);
    unlink($_POST['listing_img']);

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM listings WHERE id = $idc");
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null;
}
$url = 'http://website.com/members_area/delete_listings.php';
while (ob_get_status()) {
    ob_end_clean();
}
header("Location: $url");
?>
```

Comment: You are binding `.on('click','.delete'`, but there is no `class="delete"` in your form, only a `name="delete"`

Comment: @Sean ok that seems to help. the row is now deleting however it still goes to the php page, and stall there, so I'm confused I'm I thought the point of asynchronous data transfer is so you don't have to go to another page? Should I be including the php on the page with the form?

Comment: It depends on what element you are binding to, and so what the `return false;` applies to, and if it prevents the redirection. I will post a more simplified example as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have problem with your jquery file and also in your html code.

first of all give a class to your submit button that you have used in your jquery file.

and also set button type attribute to button.

```
<input type='button' class='delete' name='delete' />
```

and also remove action attribute from your form tag.

and do your jquery stuff like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click','.delete',function(){


            var info = '';
                info += 'id='+$('#id').val();
                info += '&adlink='+$('#ad_link').val();
                info += '&listing_img='+$('#listing_img').val();

            if( confirm( 'Are you sure you want to delete?' ) ){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'yourfile.php',
                    data:info,
                    success:function(){ }
                });
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thank you. So I changed the last to lines from } to }); and adjusted the url, and replaced &adlink with &ad_link. Removed action in form and changed html to what you said. When i click button, nothing happens, nothing is deleted either.

Comment: Open your browser console and check what happened when you click on button.

Comment: using firebug, ok that helped I had a form class which i added on there. so it's deleting but it's not showing it. In other words I have to refresh the page to see the deleted item. How do i have it just slide off?

Comment: It means record is deleted. Great!!. Now you want to remove the element without refreshing the page. for that you want to use $(element).remove() method to remove the element. use it in your ajax success function.

Comment: @Munshit Azhar I give up! so I have the sql row wrapped in <div class="record<?php echo $id; ?>">, so if I use success: function(){$('.record'+id).remove();} It doesn't delete or anything. Regardless giving you the answer here if you could help me with the remove() issue I would be very grateful

Answer (score 1):

Since you are submitting using ajax, there is no need to create a full form, just simplify it down to a button. Also, take all your needed values and add them as `data-` attributes.

```
<button class="delete" data-id="<?php echo $id ?>" data-ad_link="<?php echo $ad_link ?>" data-listing_img="<?php echo $listing_img ?>" >Delete</button>
```

Then your js can be simplified to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
            var element = $(this);

            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this listing?")) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "delete_list.php",
                    data: {id: element.data("id"), ad_link: element.data("ad_link"), listing_img: element.data("listing_img") },
                    success: function() {}
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also, in your php since you are using `PDO` and `->prepare()` you should use a placeholder

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM listings WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($idc));
```

Comment: Nice answer with explanation. Welcome to 10k